# Cast multiple values in R

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to cast multiple values in R

```
asd <- data.frame(week = c(1,1,2,2), year = c("2019","2020","2019","2020"), val = c(1,2,3,4), cap = c(3,4,6,7))
```

Expected output

```
week 2019_val 2020_val 2019_cap 2020_cap
1        1       2        3        6 
2        3       4        4        7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tidyr::pivot_wider` you could do:

```r
asd <- data.frame(week = c(1,1,2,2), year = c("2019","2020","2019","2020"), val = c(1,2,3,4), cap = c(3,4,6,7))

tidyr::pivot_wider(asd, names_from = year, values_from = c(val, cap), names_glue = "{year}_{.value}")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>    week `2019_val` `2020_val` `2019_cap` `2020_cap`
#>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1          1          2          3          4
#> 2     2          3          4          6          7
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this in base R, you can use `reshape`:

```r
reshape(asd, direction = "wide", idvar = "week", timevar = "year", sep = "_")
#>   week val_2019 cap_2019 val_2020 cap_2020
#> 1    1        1        3        2        4
#> 3    2        3        6        4        7
```

Note that it is best *not* to start your new column names with the year, since variable names beginning with numbers are not legal in R, and therefore always need to be quoted. It becomes quite tiresome to write `asd$'2020_val'` rather than `asd$val_2020` and can often lead to errors when one forgets the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

For completion, here is `data.table` option -

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(asd), week~year, value.var = c('val', 'cap'))

#   week val_2019 val_2020 cap_2019 cap_2020
#1:    1        1        2        3        4
#2:    2        3        4        6        7
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different approach using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` together:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

asd %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(week, year)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(year, name)
  )
```

```
   week `2019_val` `2019_cap` `2020_val` `2020_cap`
  <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1          1          3          2          4
2     2          3          6          4          7
```